# Replacing underscores with spaces PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to search in a array and replace all the occurrences of underscores to spaces and then implode this array to string with a new line character.

However, I'm facing difficulties in replacing underscores from an array.

**Here's my code:**

```
$array = array('this_that','is','an','array');



function fixArrayKey(&$arr)
{
    $arr=array_combine(array_map(function($str){return str_replace("_"," ",$str);},array_keys($arr)),array_values($arr));
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
    {
        if(is_array($val)) fixArrayKey($arr[$key]);
    }
}

fixArrayKey($array);
print_r($array);
```

**EDIT 1:**

I also want to search for all the entries of `true` and to replace that to `YES` in the same array, what is the optimal solution for this goal.

Comment: This code is specifically to fix underscores found in *keys* of your array, not for values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
$array = array('this_that','is','an','array');

array_walk_recursive($array,function(&$v){
    $v = str_replace('_',' ',$v);
});

print_r($array);
```

Comment: nice and clean solution. +1 for such effort

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` is overkill here: you could do the same thing with `array_map` unless you really need to nest arrays

Comment: @Andrea op's code is recursive so I assumed that's what was wanted but yes if you don't need recursion then `array_map` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array('this_that','is','an','array true');

function fixArrayKey(&$arr)
{
    $arr=array_combine(array_keys($arr),array_map(function($str){return str_replace(Array('true','_'),Array('YES',' '),$str);},array_values($arr)));
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
    {
        if(is_array($val)) fixArrayKey($arr[$key]);
    }
return $arr;
}

fixArrayKey($array);
print_r($array); 

echo implode("\n",$array);
```